# how to correctly display double quotations using PHPWord?

Tags: php, utf-8, htmlspecialchars, quotations, phpword

well I have been banging my head against the wall trying to fix this for a couple of months already. I have a legacy MySQL database which can be described as character hell. After a lot of work I was able to fix all of the incorrectly displayed characters and made everything UTF-8(tables, collation, connection to db, headers, etc).

Now the problem is that when I try to create a Word Document using PHPWord, the double quotations(") appear as its html entity equivalent `&quot;`. That is the only obstacle between me an victory so, if there's any ideas I'll be very thankfull.

Here is the code:

```
include_once "../PHPWord.php";
include_once "../debug.php";

$file_name = "filename.docx";
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
//header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

$index = 1218;
$mysqli = new mysqli("host","user","pass","database");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$qry1 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE index = $index ORDER BY field DESC";
$qry2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE index = $index";

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

$section->addText("Connection Encoding: ".$mysqli->character_set_name());
$section->addText("resuls");

$res1 = $mysqli->query($qry1);
while($row = $res1->fetch_assoc()){
    $section->addText($row[name]);
    $section->addText(mb_detect_encoding($row['name']));
}

$section->addText("results2");

$res2 = $mysqli->query($qry2);
while($row = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
    $section->addText(trim($row['title']));
    $section->addText(mb_detect_encoding($row['title']));
}

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord,'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

The result, something like this:

```
book:&quot;Book Title&quot;
```

So far I've tried a lot of functions and solutions including PHP functions like html_entity_decode, escape characters, and modified PHPWord files to prevent them to try and re-encode the text when adding it to the output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to use 
[msqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

somewhere in your query
or else, maybe this has the solution for you:
[phpWord handling of UTF-8](http://phpword.codeplex.com/discussions/261365/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already tried the second link you posted and I keep getting the same result. The first link, it will come handy when feeding the DB, but so far my problem is that when I fetch the information, php converts my quotes in html entities even with magic quotes disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest version (0.8) of PHPWord from [GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord). This version has handled UTF-8 problem.